# Leaderboard system for Python game

Tags: python

As part of my 20 hour gcse computing project I need to create a leaderboard system. I have got to this so far, and I don't know what to do from here:

```
elif Player1_Score > Player2_Score:
    print("\nCongratulations", name1, "You have won")
    leaderscore = [name1, Player1_Score]
    else:
        print("\nCongratulations", name2, "You have won")
        leaderscore = [name2,Player2_Score]
leaderboard = open("leaderboard.txt", "w")

leaderboard.write(leaderscore[0] + ',' + str(leaderscore[1]) + '\n')

leaderboard.close()

with open ("leaderboard.txt") as leaderboard:
    for leaderscore[1] in leaderboard:
        leaderboard.append(leaderscore[1].strip())

leaderboard.sort(int(leaderscore[1]))
print(leaderboard)

with open ("sorted_leaderscore.txt", 'w') as u:
    for leaderscore[1] in leaderboard:
        u.write(leaderscore[1] + "\n")
```

I get this error message:

```
ing\NEA\NEA code.py", line 162, in <module>
    leaderboard.append(leaderscore[1].strip())
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'append'
```

And finally I need help outputting the top 5 scores into my main program.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say `leaderboard.append(leaderscore[1].strip())`, what are you expecting it to do exactly? Do you want it to write `leaderscore[1].strip()` to the file `leaderboard.txt`? If so, you need to invoke `leaderboard.write(leaderscore[1].strip())`, and `open` your file in a read/write mode (`+`). `leaderboard` is a file-like object, but you are treating it like it's a list.

Comment: I'm not sure as I'm quite new to the programming language .leaderscore[0] is a string - the name of the player. leaderscore[1] is an integer value, and I am trying to sort all of these integer values that are in the external file. I did my research and came out short. I've tried what you have suggested and there is a new error:ing\NEA\NEA code.py", line 161, in <module>
    leaderboard.write(leaderscore[1].strip())
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable